# Understanding wiktionary template tags

Tags: mediawiki

I am looking at the wiktionary dump [for Dutch](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/nlwiktionary/20240101/), its "All pages, current versions only." archive. While some of the template tags are generally, some are more specific but I cannot find any information about them so this question relates to the data structure of the wiktionary dumps.

For instance, this is part of a page dump of ["ja"](https://nl.wiktionary.org/wiki/ja):

```
{{=nld=}}
{{-pron-}}
*{{sound}}: {{audio|nl-ja.ogg|ja|nld}}
*{{WikiW|IPA}}: {{IPA-nl-standaard|ja}};  {{IPA|/jaː/|nld}}
{{-syll-}}
*ja
{{-etym-}}
* In de betekenis van ‘tussenwerpsel: uitroep ter bevestiging’ voor het eerst aangetroffen in het jaar 1240 {{sijs|976}} {{ebank|ja1|ja (tussenwerpsel ter bevestiging of instemming)}}
{{-adverb-|nld}}
'''ja'''
#duidt bevestiging, instemming, toestemming, inwilliging of toegeving aan
{{bijv-1|Heeft hij dat echt gezegd? '''Ja'''.}}
```

Obviously it is clear what these are from looking at the page: they indicate headings with predefined heading identifiers which are then localized for the correct language. But where is this defined? How can I for instance find an overview of `nld` to the corresponding text that gets rendered (here "Nederlands") or from `{{-etym-}}` to "Etymologie"? Or are these localization "dictionaries" not available?

Comment: Are you looking for templates like https://nl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sjabloon:-adverb-?

Comment: @Progman That pointed me in the right direction, indeed. For instance, https://nl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sjabloon:-etym-. This seems like a tag specific for Dutch. But it does not seem explicitly linked to etymology tags for other languages as far as I can see unfortunately. That is what I was sort of hoping for but it seems that every language community can kind of do their own thing.